# How to refresh 3 database driven div(s) using JQuery And Codeigniter/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, jquery

First of all, accept my apology for lengthy code and explanation as I am new to JQuery and i have a very specific case here.

I have created a dashboard in admin panel of my project for employees,students and courses.
I have three DIVs where i am pulling employee's record,student records and courses separately.I have made my div(s) draggable and round cornered using the code below:

**CSS**

```
 #draggable { width: 600px;vertical-align: top; }
 #draggable2 { width: 600px; }#draggable3 { width: 600px; }
 #divheader {width:100%px; background-color: #C50C2F; color:#fff;font-weight: 500;  border-color:#C50C2F;}
 #divheader2 {width:100%px; background-color: #C50C2F; color:#fff;font-weight: 500;  border-color:#C50C2F;}
 #divheader3 {width: 700px; float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0; background-color: #C50C2F; color:#fff;font-weight: 500;  border-color:#C50C2F;}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
 });

 $("#draggable").corner();
 $("#divheader").corner();

 $(function() {
  $( "#draggable2").draggable();
 });
 $("#draggable2").corner();
 $("#divheader2").corner();

$(function() {
$("#draggable3").draggable();
});
$("#draggable3").corner();
$("#divheader3").corner();

</script>
```

I have also added two links for "REFRESH" and "Hide" to refresh and hide div(s) separately.

CODE TO PULL & SHOW DATA FROM DATABASE:

```
 <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="width:700px; vertical-align: top;" align="center" >
  <div id="divheader">Employees<a href="#" ><img src="/images/admin/icons/minimize.png" title="Hide Employee panel" alt="Hide" height="20px;" width="20px;" align="right">       </a>&nbsp;
  <a href="/secure/admin/" ><img src="/images/admin/icons/refresh.png" title="Refresh Employee Records" alt="Refresh" height="20px;" width="20px;" align="right"></a> 
   </div> 
 <div id="adminHeaders">
<div class="adminOverviewBlockTitle" align="left" >Name</div>
 <div class="adminOverviewBlockTitle">Job Title</div>
<div class="adminOverviewBlockTitle" >Start Date</div>
 <div class="adminOverviewBlockTitle" >Date Left</div>
  <div class="adminOverviewBlockTitle" >Status</div>
   <div class="adminOverviewCells emptyblockimg" ></div>
 </div>
<script>
$( "a" ).click(function() {
 $("#draggable").hide();
});
</script>

<div>

<?

if (isset($sets))
{
 foreach ($sets as $key=>$pos)
  {
?>

 <div class="adminOverviewBlockTitle" align="left" ><?=$pos->name?></div>
 <div class="adminOverviewBlockTitle" ><?=$pos->title?></div>
 <div class="adminOverviewBlockTitle" ><?=$pos->date_entered?></div>
 <div class="adminOverviewBlockTitle" ><?=$pos->date_left?></div>
  <div class="adminOverviewBlockTitle" ><?=$pos->status?></div>
  <div class="adminOverviewBlocksCells emptyblockimg" ><a href="<?=base_url()?>secure/mpt/edit/<?=$pos->id?>" ><img border="0" src="/images/admin/icons/pencil.png" alt="Edit" width="20px;" height="20px;"  alt=""></a></div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <?}
  }
  ?>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and the same is for other 2 DIVs..

BUT the problem is that:

**1)** How can i hide individual DIV on each hyperlink?

**2)** I want to pull data from database into specific DIV when " Refresh" link is clicked without Refreshing the whole page or other DIVs?

Please help me.How can i achieve this using Jquery/Ajax and PHP/Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to send request and receive response from server help you to pull data from db:

```
function pull_data(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?=base_url()?>data_pull/show_data', //url to controller,
        data:'id='+id,//If you have to send some data to server then send it here
        success:function(response){
            $("#show-div").show();
            $("#hide-div").hide();
                            $("#replace-div").html(response);
        }
    });
}
  //I assume that your controller name is data_pull and your function name is show_data();
    code for that is
public function show_data(){
    $id=$this->input->post('id');
    //write your mysql query over here in $data array.Save your div html in a file and load it as

    echo $this->load->view('place-your-div-html',$data,true);
}
```

and from HTML call this function as

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onCLick="pull_data(id)">Refresh</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Naeem.I have two links "Hide" and "Refresh"..How can implement this on Refresh click event?Sorry i am new to Jquery

Comment: Naeem, if you can ensure that your answers have good indentation, you'll spot missing braces more easily.

Comment: simlply call on click event.See answer I have edited it for you

Comment: But how can i pull data from database using AJAX/Jquery?The above code is pulling data using simple mysql queries.